# pandas: how to skip a row while aggregating a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
actor          Daily Total   actor1  actor2
Day
2019-01-01     25            10       15
2019-01-02     30            15       15
Total          55            25       30
```

I want to calculate the average of each column as follows:

```
actor          Daily Total   actor1  actor2
Day
2019-01-01     25            10       15
2019-01-02     30            15       15
Total          55            25       30
Avg            27.5          12.5     15.0
```

But if I use `df.loc['Avg'] = df.mean()`, it would consider 'Total' row also. How can I skip the 'Total' row while calculating the average?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove row with `drop`:

```
df.loc['Avg'] = df.drop('Total').mean()
```

Or select all rows without last:

```
df.loc['Avg'] = df.iloc[:-1].mean()
```